# Pass command line argument to child process from parent Node js

Tags: python, node.js, command, child-process

I am calling python function from node js file

My Python File

```
predictedResult = predictPicture(str(sys.argv[1]))
print(predictedResult)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

It takes an argument from command line as a parameter.

Node js file

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ["./xxxxx.py"]);

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
    dataToSend = data.toString();
});
```

I want to pass a command line argument to my child process.

I want to pass many arguments in for each loop and log result.

Is there any way that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

`spawn` function takes three arguments

1. `command`: `python`
2. `[args]`: `["./xxxxx.py", "arg1", "arg2"]`
3. `[options]`: You don't need this here

The first item in the `args` array is the script name, followed by any other optional arguments.

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ["./xxxxx.py", "arg1", "arg2"]);
```

Now your python script should receive the

```
predictedResult = predictPicture(str(sys.argv[1]))
# sys.argv[1] -> "arg1"
print(predictedResult)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Yes. The thing is I want to run that process once and pass different arguments each time. Like run process once and loop different argument each time.

Comment: The `std input` args can only be passed when running the script for the first time, once it's running, you cannot pass args anymore! Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Is there any way I can run child process once and pass arguments at runtime ?

Comment: No. It's either you use sockets to exchange data in runtime, or spawn a new python script every time you need to pass w new argument.

Comment: Any example for ref?

Comment: I believe this might help. https://pypi.org/project/NodeSocket/